# Django tutorial 5 testing "response = client.get(reverse('polls:index'))"

Tags: python, django

I get these errors when I run

```
response = client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
```

https://pastebin.com/wJU0zBZr

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial05/ using tutorial

What is wrong?

Comment: add your ```template``` (```.html```) as well.

Comment: You mean index.html ? This one https://pastebin.com/R4bNd1qu  is good?

Comment: If ```index.html``` is the only template you have, then yes. The problem lies there.If you have more than one template then you can find it by tracking the ```url``` you are testing on.

Comment: I have 2 more in my mysite/polls/templates/polls https://pastebin.com/btpAeprz https://pastebin.com/TuDfj9mC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `index.html`. In the following line :

```
{% for question in latest_question_list %}
```

you opened a `for` tag and forgot to close it by `endfor`.